# iPhone app does not look the same on iPad

Tags: ios, ios8, compatibility, screen-resolution

I developed an iPhone only app. Before I tried to submit the new version (for iOS 8, iPhone 6 / 6 Plus adaptability), the app had exactly the same look on both iPhone and iPad. 
I did not change anything except the nav bar image and the xcassets in order to add new icons and launch screens.
I don't use any Launch Screen File.
My app works well on all iPhone resolutions but have some troubles on iPad.

**EDIT :** It's not an universal app. I'm using XIB files and I'm not using Autolayout.

Here are an example :

[image: iPhone 4S screenshot]

[image: iPhone 6 screenshot]

[image: iPad screenshot x2]

[image: iPad screenshot x1]

What can I do in order to have exactly the same on both iPhone / iPad ?

Comment: Did you used Storyboard ?

Comment: No, I use XIB files.

Comment: Can you pls also attach a screenshot when it is in 1x zoom mode on iPad?

Comment: I edited my post, I just added it.

Comment: How do you resize the "plate" view? From the looks of it, it is THE view that is resizing to make space for other views when screen estate is 3:4.

Comment: I resize and replace manually each element which need to be resized and replaced, autolayout was too hard to set up for this kind of view.

Comment: It worked well before I try to adapt my app for iOS 8 / iPhone 6 / 6 Plus.